# How to give a link in cell with other cell value in ag-grid in Angular?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to create a clickable cell having urllink of other cell which I am getting from my http.get call.

I am creating a ag-grid link with http.get call.
Getting data.
1- Report.
2- ReportLink.
I wanted to show Report header but don't want to show reportLink but Instead I want that report header to be clickable and redirect to the reportLink which I am getting in http.get call.

I have already check all links provide in #stackoverflow but nothing seems relevant.

```html
{
headerName:"Buy Report",
        field:"buy_report",
        width:120,
        cellStyle: { 'text-align': "left" },
        cellRenderer: function(params) {
            return '<a href="http://local.com/past-recommendations/'+params.value.toLowerCase()+'" target="_blank">'+ params.value+'</a>'
        }


onGridReady(params){
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    this.http.get("http://local.com/past-recommendations")
    .subscribe(data=>{
      this.rowData = data as any;        
    });
```

with above example I am getting link on my cell but what I want is 
cellRenderer

Instead of params.val I could use my second column (link).

I hope , I able to express what I want but if you need any clarification am ready to give more.
 I have searched a lot but nothing seems related to my query.

Hope to get an answer here now.

thank you very much in advance to give a look on this.

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/angular.php

Comment: @Dimanoid thank you but the thing is we can only use param.value, which provide the value of same cell or column, but I need the value of other cell.

like 
 '<a href="'+params-col2.value.toLowerCase()+'" target="_blank">'+ params-col1.value+'</a>'

Comment: Ah, probably I misunderstood the question. Docs (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/ ) says that `params` has `data` and `rowIndex` properties that you could use to get current row and any cell from it.

Comment: @Dimanoid I check that but using angular and its bit confusing to check and implement.

Comment: Print `params` to console in `cellRenderer` function to see what properties It has. I think that will clarify most questions.

Comment: I was getting nothing until I import ICellrendererparams and use that as parameter.
Now its solved.

thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `params` argument you receive for the `cellRenderer` is of type `ICellRendererParams`.

You can access data associated with the row for the cell as below.

```
cellRenderer: (params: ICellRendererParams) => {
   params.data    // here the data is the row object you need
   return `<a href="YOUR_URL/${params.data.PROP_VALUE}">${params.value}</a>`;
}
```

Comment: it that case also I have to show or first render that column in my ag-grid row which I don't want to do.
meanwhile Can you give little more in your answer like which type of ICellRendererParams you asking to crate for this.

Thank you.

Comment: Its already there, just `import { ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grd-community'`

Comment: `I have to show or first render that column in my ag-grid row which I don't want to do.` - not clear what r u asking. By this, you can render data related to another column in the first column. That's what you've asked in the question.

Comment: import { ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grid-community';
And @Paritosh ans worked for me.
thanks